# Efficiently updating large amount of core-data records

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

After getting the list of user uids from the server I need to update a fairly large amount of Users object with the same value. The server returns an array of user id's like this:

```
{
    "ids": [1, 2, 3, 4]
}
```

There can be 100+ id's here (the local users table holds 2k+ records), so I am looking for as efficient approach as possible. First I need to put the already isOpened values to 0. In SQL terms I need to do something like this:

```
UPDATE users SET isClosed = 0 WHERE isClosed = 1

UPDATE users SET isClosed = 1 WHERE userId IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Basically I am solving a problem when user hasn't used the app for a long period of time, to mass update the isClosed attribute.

Now, to the server fetching and "mapping" part of the problem. I couldn't figure how to do a proper restkit request without mapping the response to objects ... Please advise if there is a more proper way of doing this ... so I am doing a basic restkit/afnetworking get request:

```
[[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] HTTPClient] getPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/api/%@/closeUsers", [[MyCredentialStore sharedInstance] userId]]
parameters:nil
success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

NSArray *userIDs = [responseObject objectForKey:@"ids"];
    NSLog(@"%@", userIDs);
    // 1. set the default value for isClosed (0) for all users
    // 2. update the users with userIDs to isClosed = 1
}
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // response code is in operation.response.statusCode
}];
```

Now how can I do 1. and 2. in the success block? Or is there a proper restkit-way of doing batch updates likes this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the amount of data you indicate, just a simple loop is very efficient.

```
NSArray *closedUsers = [allUsers filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
        [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isClosed = %@", @1]];
NSArray *usersFromServer = [allUsers filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
        [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userID IN %@", userIDs];

for (User *user in closedUsers) {
   user.isClosed = @0; 
}
for (User *user in usersFromServer) {
   user.isClosed = @1;
}
```

You can test this - with plain Core Data should take a split second.

Comment: Works like a charm. And it's pretty fast. Don't know why I was concerned about the performance.